# Нельзя преобразовать тип boolean к real

Tags: pascal

```
Program P1;
var a, b,x  : real;
function p(a,b:real):real;
begin
    p:=sqrt(a*x+b=0);
end;
begin
    write('Vvedite 4sla');
    read(a, b);
    otvet:=p(a, b);
    write('p=', otvet:10:2);
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Ахахаах корень уравнения и извлечения корня разные вещи.

Comment: Я голосую против этого вопроса, т.к не отражает стремления разобраться

Comment: @4per ну код есть, значит что-то она делала и пыталась, разве нет? или тут пустой текст без кода?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я оставляю комментарий не для публичного обсуждения моего решения, а для того, чтобы автор или потенциальный редактор, могли понять за что минус. Также у этого человека, появится возможность уведомить меня об улучшении вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

И что вы хотите тут вычислить?

```
sqrt(a*x+b=0)
```

Вы сравниваете `ax+b` с нулем, и хотите извлечь корень из *результата сравнения*? Точно? :)

Раз [@alexolut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut) считает, что это не ответ, а я просто пытаюсь сдуру спросить, что это вы такое считаете, разжую для совсем ... гм, чайников.

*[Скучным менторским тоном] Выражение `a*x+b=0` в Паскале есть выражение сравнения, возвращающее булево значение `True/False`, каковое не является числовым значением, из которого можно вычислить квадратный корень... Вы можете выполнить приведение типов, используя конструкцию вида `sqrt(byte(a*x+b=0))`.*

Ну и еще - переменная `otvet` у вас не объявлена.

Comment: Думать самому полезно, безусловно. Но формат вопросов/ответов SO подразумевает необходимость наличия ответа в сообщении из секции "ответы", а не уточняющих вопросов для дальнейших размышлений.

Comment: @alexolut это верно только для тех вопросов, которые собираются оставить на сайте. А этот вопрос в любом случае пойдет на удаление.

Comment: @PavelMayorov наличие ответов с плюсами уменьшает вероятность удаления вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut зато голосование за удаление эту вероятность повышает xD

Comment: @PavelMayorov поясните, пожалуйста, в какой ситуации данный вопрос при наличии ответа с плюсом может быть удалён.